# Execute parse develop command on nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm using Parse as backend but their log system is hard to read. So I tried to execute the command "parse develop " inside a nodejs script to make what they log more readable but I can't make it work.

```
// var spawn  = require('child_process').spawn;
var exec  = require('child_process').exec;   
var child = exec('parse', ['develop', 'MyApp']);

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('This is never called');
});
child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('This works'); 
});
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `spawn` instance of `exec`

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    parse = spawn('parse-develop',['MyApp']);

parse.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

parse.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

parse.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Comment: I have also tried spawn but still it is not getting fired.

Comment: The execute command what you want to run is `parse develop MyApp` right? Testing on my computer is work well

Comment: I think your in round command Parse Develop should run `parse-develop MyApp`

Comment: `parse develop MyApp` works normal on the terminal but on the nodejs script it doesn't. Both exec and spawn. `parse-develop` is a script made by someone else but that's not what I want to use.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Parse's CLI and it looks like the parse develop command has been removed!